# data-toggle and data-target are not recognized as attributes by HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask

i am currently in the process of developing a website but i cannot get the data-toggle and data-target attributes to be recognized in my code (they don't change to the color of recognized attributes in html).

my sample code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{% block title %}FoLA^2{%endblock%}</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href= "{{url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            .sidenav {height: 100%; /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
                        width: 240px; /* Set the width of the sidebar */
                        position: fixed; /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
                        z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
                        top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
                        left: 0;
                        background-color: #DCDCDC; 
                        overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
                        padding-top: 20px;}

            .sidenav a {padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        font-size: 25px;
                        color: #808080;
                        display: block;}

            .sidenav a:hover {color: #696969;}

            .jumbotron {margin-left: 240px;
            height: 175px}

            .content {margin-left: 300px}

            .form-group {width: 220px; margin-left: 10px}
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="sidenav">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail1" placeholder="Ëmail address">
            </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="InputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" style="margin-left: 75px; margin-bottom: 5px">Log In</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerModal" style="margin-left: 68px; margin-bottom: 60px">Register</button>
        <div class="modal fade" id="#registerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                ...
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        </form>

        <a href="/" style="font-size: 200%"> Home </a>
        <a href="/cards/" style="font-size: 200%"> Playing Cards </a>
        <a href="/links/" style="font-size: 200%"> Links </a>
        <a href="/contact/" style="font-size: 200%"> Contact </a>


    </div>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4"> FoLA^2 </h1>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <div class="content">
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <hr />


    <footer style="margin-left: 300px; position: fixed; bottom: 0">
        <p> <a href="https://dataintelligence.zuyd.nl/"> Data Intelligence Zuyd</a>; 2020</p>
    </footer>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I imported JQuery, Popper, and bootstrap in that order but i am still not able to get my code to recognize these attributes (and a couple of others from jQuery i think.

this is what is looks like in my editor:

[screenshot of editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Y9C.png)

I've browsed about a dozen other answers involving these two attributes but i can't find a solution that applies to me.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do they work in your code? Like if you try to get them with jquery? Because that is what really matters

Comment: @Dejan.S Hi there, no they do not work with the code I provided.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a big deal actually, It will not throw any error in your code when you run it.

**Data Attributes** are introduced in `HTML5`, So you don't need any libraries like `jQuery` or `Popper`. It will work fine on **Modern Browsers** natively.

**The issue is**, your **editor is not compatible** with **HTML5**. Seems you are using **Notepad++**.

---

**I Recommend you to do,**

- Update your editor
- Use some advanced `IDEs` / `Editors` like [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), [Atom](https://atom.io/) and [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer!
I would like to clarify that the code also does not work currently, as in I can't get the modal to show up. It is the Demo modal from Bootstrap with the ID changed so i think it should work, just seems like my code somehow isn't correct.

Comment: @JoelGeorges update your code with your implementation for the modal.

Comment: It is the same code as in my original post. I took the Demo Modal from bootstrap and changed the id to correspond to the id that my button calls under data-target.

Answer (score 0):

I guess,you don't need to add '#' while  calling the modal!!!

Comment: <div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">